# Rolling count over the last n days

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I have the following dataframe:

```
entry_time_flat           route_id      time_slot          

2019-09-02 00:00:00           1_2            0-6
2019-09-04 00:00:00           3_4            6-12
2019-09-06 00:00:00           1_2            0-6
2019-09-06 00:00:00           1_2           18-20
...
```

I would like to create a final_df that, for each route_id and time_slot, computes the number of occurrences over the last n_days (with n_days = 30).

To illustrate, I'd like to obtain the following df:

```
print(final_df)

entry_time_flat           route_id      time_slot    n_occurrences        

2019-09-02 00:00:00           1            0-6             0
2019-09-04 00:00:00           3            6-12            0
2019-09-06 00:00:00           1            0-6             1
2019-09-06 00:00:00           1            18-20           0
...
```

How can I efficiently achieve that result?

Comment: What is the logic behind this ?

Comment: group by time_slot and route_id and count the number of rows of each subset

Comment: `df['n'] = df.groupby(['route_id', 'time_slot']).cumcount()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.rolling` with an offset:

```
# set date column as index, make sure it is sorted
df.set_index('entry_time_flat',inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

# define offset
n_days = 30
offset = str(n_days)+'D'

# count
final_df = df.groupby(['route_id','time_slot'])['route_id'].rolling(offset,closed='left').count()
final_df.fillna(0,inplace=True)

# get desired output format
final_df.name = 'n_occurrences'
final_df = final_df.reset_index()
```

Edit: looks like you want the interval to be left-closed. Changed the answer accordingly.